# Getting access to NSPopover window to set level?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopover

When a popover shows, I'm curious whether it's possible to set the underlying settings on the popover's window, such as the window level.  In my testing, popovers seem to be a window, but they doesn't respond to normal `NSWindow` selectors, such as `setLevel:`.

Is it possible to set the window level on a `NSPopover`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NSPopover` is a subclass of `NSObject`, not `NSWindow`, so setting the window level is not officially supported.

You could try getting the window like this:

```
NSWindow* popoverWindow = yourPopover.contentViewController.view.window;
```

I have no idea whether you can then successfully set the level though.

Comment: Great work! Accessing the view's window just slipped my mind.  Thanks.

Comment: it's worth noting that you can get the window this way but not with [NSApp mainWindow]

Comment: You can certainly adjust the level of the window this way.  But the window isn't instantiated until the popover has actually been displayed.  I make such configurations each time I display the popover as I am unclear on the persistence of the supporting window.